# How to do a get request to SpringBoot java with an Array<Array<string>>?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, jpa, get

I am doing a get request in angular with typescript and here it is:

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/data-management/data-users/getAllGeneralInfoCV/"+this.listAllCharacteristicsToFind);
```

The attributte "listAllCharacteristicsToFind" is an `Array<Array<string>>`. For example, in this case, listAllCharacteristicsToFind[0] will be an array of two strings: [B2,C1].  I have in the controller in Java with SpringBoot this method:

```
@GetMapping("data-users/getAllGeneralInfoCV/{listAllCharacteristicsToFind}")
    public List<DataCV2> getAllGeneralInfoCV(@PathVariable ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listAllCharacteristicsToFind){
        System.out.println(listAllCharacteristicsToFind);
        return findUserDataCVService.findAllGeneralCV(listAllCharacteristicsToFind.get(0),listAllCharacteristicsToFind.get(1), listAllCharacteristicsToFind.get(2), listAllCharacteristicsToFind.get(3), listAllCharacteristicsToFind.get(4), listAllCharacteristicsToFind.get(5));
}
```

In the system.out.println I can see that the array it gets to the controller is [[B2], [C1], [], [], [], [], []]. However, it should be [[B2, C1], [], [], [], [], []]. In Angular it is okey, so what's the problem?

Comment: Could you show your request? What really has in `this.listAllCararctersToFind`? in  addition there is no sense on readindg a list in controller then get each position maybe do you need a map in request?

Comment: This is what listAllCharacteristicsToFind has: (6) [Array(2), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0)]
0: (2) ['B2', 'C1']
1: []
2: []
3: []
4: []
5: []

Comment: I need a list because I need each array in a specific position